# Can I install visual studio 2012 side by side with 2010?

Tags: windows-7, installation, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

Can I install Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2012 RTM side by side with Visual Studio Ultimate 2010 on Windows 7?

Because I tried to install it and I just got the splash screen for the installer then I got the following error:

`Setup detected an issue during the operation. Please click below to check for a solution and help us improve the setup experience.`

And nothing happens! no solution found! although I've setup the same copy into Windows 8 successfully.

Any Ideas?

Comment: What does it tell you when you "click below"?

Comment: @techie007 just submit the error to Microsoft then I get they didn't find a solution for this and I got nothing logged to the Event viewer!

Comment: Yes of course you can.  I have VS2003 through VS2012 installed on my developer machine.

Comment: How much old your Windows 7 installation is? If it very old then I would suggest you to try a fresh setup of Windows and then install it again. Sometime some components missed out from the windows and can't be fixed then we have to do a fresh installation. I have been faced this kind of issue with other software.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I looked into the logs in %temp% (thanks to @ganeshr for pointing me to the right location to the logs) and I found that errot:

```
ERROR: The type initializer for 'System.Windows.Media.FontFamily' threw an exception.
```

I searched the internet and found that it's a WPF font issue, this link helped me understanding where is the issue came from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9066930/wpf-window-crashes-on-startup-or-it-starts-but-hangs-and-does-not-render-conten

I did some font clean up, removed unused fonts for me and I think because I had a lot of update for the default installer font: Segeo UI this cause the error. I removed the old updates and finally the installer opens.

Thanks for you your all support.

**EDIT**: BTW I had to restart the following services and not sure if this is relevant/fixes the issue:

- Windows Font Cache Service
- Windows Presentation Foundation Font Cache 3.0.0.0

Comment: +1 just for posting solution to an edge case that can be found on Google

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can install Visual Studion 2012 side by side to 2010 on Windows 7. I have this installed and running well on my System.

To solve your problem, I suggest trying to re-download the setup and try again. Also, are there any more defined error messages or codes?

Comment: +1 Make sure that you update Visual Studio 2010 to SP1 incase you want to open VS 2010 projects in VS 2012 without upgrading the projects.

Comment: @Michael-K is it acceptable that the iso file can be installed successfully on Win 8 and fails on Wind 7?

Comment: @ganeshR my visual studio 2010 is updates to the latest with SP1 and till today updates!

Comment: @AMgdy those are different systems. I assume that your win7 installation is not fresh. Therefore it might be a lot of stuff on the system that might be a problem.
I just assumed a broken download, because that would be a common behavior for errors like this.

Comment: @AMgdy no its not acceptable that the same ISO is corrupted on Win 7. May be there are some components are missed out or you are missing any Windows update?

Comment: I found some new updates I will install it and try again; otherwise I've to re-download the iso again!

Comment: @AMgdy I don't think downloading the iso again will change anything if it works on one system. It is much more likely that there is an error on the system where it doesn't work.

Comment: @AMgdy Can you try posting your issue on Visual Studio Setup and Installation forum: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssetup/threads . First:
collect your install logs with this:
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=E0DA314F-6216-4A18-BC6B-7D29CF83AF20&amp;displaylang=e&displaylang=en
After you run Collect.exe, you'll find vslogs.cab in your %temp% directory. Upload vslogs.cab to a public site, like SkyDrive, and post the link to the Visual Studio setup forum.